# SSIS Oracle Source - DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER

Tags: oracle, ssis, sql-server-2019

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 to get data from a Oracle Database and transfer it to a SQL 2019 database. I'm using Oracle connection (Connection Manager for Oracle Connections) for my source and an OLE DB connection for my SQL 2019 database. Test connection work fine for both and when I execute the package in VS2019, it works fine.

When I deploy it to SQL2019 and run it from a agent job, I get a DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER error. I have seen some forums and done following changes,

1. In VS2019 Run64BitRuntime to false
2. In agent job, checked it to run in 32bit mode
3. Installed MicrosoftSSISOracleConnector on the server containing SQL2019

Tired by setting DTS property to EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey and with password too.
Also tried DelayValidation with True and with False.

But no joy so far. Has anyone troubleshooted this in past and can shed some light on this please?

Deepak

Comment: Are VS2019 and SQL2019 running in the same server? If not, how about oracle connection settings (tnsnames.ora, etc), do they match between machines (plus firewall settings, etc.)?

Comment: Hi @Gigga,
VS2019 is on a development box. SQL 2019 is on a windows server. When running the package manually from the development box, it runs fine. The tnsname is identical on both dev box and on the server. And both Dev box and the server are allowed to connect to Oracle cloud on a specific port.

Comment: What kind of authentication is needed to SQL Server, windows auhtentication or username/password? If windows auth, does the Agent credentials have the permission to the database the SSIS is using?

Comment: It takes a windows account (agent account) for SQL login which works fine. But I finally got it sorted. Used EZConnect method for Oracle and updated to the latest SQL server build.

Comment: Nice work! You should write that as a reply to your question and mark it as the answer. That way others get the information about this kind of issue.

Comment: Nice idea. done. :)

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it sorted. Was given very useful tips from a professional on Microsoft forums.

I used the **EZConnect** (to avoid using TNS names which was problematic on the server) method for Oracle in the connection manager. Kept the **SQL Server 2019 to the latest build**. Removed the 32-bit and **installed the 64-bit MS Oracle Connector** on the SQL Server and it worked.