# SQL Server job doesnt detect connection in SSIS package

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2017

I have VS2017 installed on the server. I am trying to schedule opsjob on sql server 2017.
But it is not recogonising the Oracle connection. The package works perfectly on VS2017 on the same server. Its using the Microsoft connector.

When I load the package in the SQL server job, I am able to see the sql server connections in the package but not the Oracle connection . Can someone guide on this please.

[image]

Some part of error

> Cannot find the connection manager with ID "{89E8-08C-4D-BE47-D1F0}"
> in the connection manager collection due to error code 0xC0010009.
> That connection manager is needed by "Oracle
> Source.Connections[MSOraConnection]" in the connection manager
> collection of "Oracle Source". Verify that a connectio

Comment: Most likely this is because Visual Studio runs the 32 bit configuration of your package while your SQL Server Agent will run the x64 configuration. You could either install the x64 Oracle drivers or force 32 bit execution of your package.

Comment: My package doesnt require oracle client. I am using EXconnect to connect. I tried to execute the job in 32 bit but no help.

Comment: [SSIS Oracle Source - DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67006087/205233) suggests to install the x64 Oracle connector.

Comment: I have already installed 64 bit connector. We have moved from an older version of attunity and I can see the attunity connection in the old jobs which are now disabled. but the new one is not recogonising the oracle connection in the connection manager.

Comment: I've had similar issues when *renaming* the connection manager. It looked ok in Visual Studio but the connection manager was not visible on SQL Server after deployment. After I renamed it (again) and re-deployed it was visible again.